# Kotlin: objectmapper.readValue() with TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> cannot infer parameter

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I would like to deserialize a json to Map with objectmapper with the following code:

```
fun onMessage(topic: String, message: MqttMessage) {
   val typeRef = object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {}
   val msg = objectMapper.readValue(message.payload, typeRef)
   ...
}
```

Compiler says it connot infer parameter T in `fun <T : Any!> readValue (src: ByteArray!, valueTypeRef: (TypeReference<Any!>..TypeReference<*>?)): T!`

Is there any solution to this problem whitout extending a HashMap with my custom class like this:

```
class MyHashMap : HashMap<String, String>()
```

...

```
fun onMessage(topic: String, message: MqttMessage) {
   val msg = objectMapper.readValue(message.payload, MyHashMap::class.java)
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why is the negative vote?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue, really, is in Jackson's API here. Here's how the `readValue` method is declared:

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
```

They are using the raw type of `TypeReference` for some reason, even though they could easily take a `TypeReference<T>` as their parameter. If they did, you code would work as is, as Kotlin could then infer the `T` generic type parameter of the function, and therefore know its return type.

You can work around this issue a couple different ways, however, by being explicit with your types.

- Either by providing the generic type parameter for the function, and having the type of the `msg` variable inferred:

  ```
    val typeRef: TypeReference<Map<K, V>> = object : TypeReference<Map<K, V>>() {} 
    val msg = objectMapper.readValue<HashMap<String, String>>(message.payload, typeRef)
  ```
- Or alternatively, by explicitly typing your variable, and having the function's type parameter inferred:

  ```
    val msg: HashMap<String, String> = objectMapper.readValue(message.payload, typeRef)
  ```

Comment: Can you show how you declared `typeRef`? I can't get your example to work.
Tried this ```val typeRef: TypeReference<List<UserInfo>> = TypeReference<List<UserInfo>> (){}``` but the IDE tells me 'cannot access <init>'

Comment: val typeRef: TypeReference<Map<K, V>> = object : TypeReference<Map<K, V>>() {}

Answer (score 6):

One possible way:

```
inline fun <reified T> ObjectMapper.readValue(s: String): T = this.readValue(s, object : TypeReference<T>() {})

val msg: Map<String,String> = objectMapper.readValue(message.payload)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#inheriting-anonymous-objects-from-supertypes) to pass an anonymous implementation of `TypeReference`:

```
objectMapper.readValue(message.payload, object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {})
```

Notice the `object`  keyword before the `TypeReference` parameter.